# Need help with calculating this sum: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{2^n}\tan\frac{1}{2^n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, trigonometry, closed-form, trigonometric-series

I need help with calculating this sum:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{2^n}\tan\frac{1}{2^n}$$

Comment: This is a very good problem. Can you tell me whether you get this from? Thank you.

Answer (score 17):

Hint: use the fact that $\cot{x}-2\cot{2 x}=\tan{x}$

Comment: Nice. Very Nice.

Comment: Awesome result and another trick for my toolbox :) +1

Answer (score 1):

i just was reading this book yesterday
[image: krishna book]

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)