# Looking for a source of an infinite trigonometric summation and other such examples.

Tags: sequences-and-series, online-resources, trigonometric-series

Question:

> If $x \neq 0$, then prove that  $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac1{2^n} \tan\left(\dfrac{x}{2^n}\right) = \dfrac1{x} - \cot x.$

My answer:

> I proved this result by using the following identity:
>
> $$ \prod_{k=1}^n \cos\left(\frac{x}{2^k}\right) = \frac{\sin x}{2^n\sin \frac{x}{2^n}}$$
>
> I took natural log on both sides of the above equation and then differentiated both sides to get
>
> $$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{2^k} \tan\left(\frac{x}{2^k}\right) = \frac{1}{2^n}\cot \left(\frac{x}{2^n}\right) - \cot x.$$
>
> Now taking the limit of $n$ to $\infty$ I get the required identity. $\blacksquare$

I have *never* seen the above identity before in my life. I was amused and surprised by this identity. That's because I have never seen an infinite trig series summing up to a rational function like $\dfrac1{x}$ before.

So my questions are the following:

A) First of all, is my derivation correct? Secondly, does anyone know a source for this problem?

B) Are there other 'elementary 'derivations that have an infinite trig series on one side and a rational function on the other?  [I say 'elementary' to avoid Fourier series. I am guessing Fourier series must be full of such results.]

Comment: Related :http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/389850/need-help-with-calculating-this-sum-sum-n-0-infty-frac12n-tan-frac1

Answer (score 2):

HINT:
Use $$\cot y-\tan y=\frac{\cos^2yx-\sin^2y}{\sin y\cos y}=2\frac{\cos2y}{2\sin y\cos y}=2\frac{\cos2y}{\sin2y}=2\cot2y$$

$$\iff \tan y=\cot y-2\cot2y $$

Putting  $y=\frac x2,\frac x{2^2},\frac x{2^3}\cdots$

$\tan \frac x2=\cot \frac x2-2\cot x $

$\tan \frac x{2^2}=\cot \frac x{2^2}-2\cot \frac x2 $

$\tan \frac x{2^3}=\cot \frac x{2^3}-2\cot \frac x{2^2} $

etc

$$\sum_{1\le r\le n} \frac1{2^r}\tan \frac x{2^r}=\frac 1{2^{n+1}}\cot \frac x{2^{n+1}}-\cot x$$

Now, putting $\frac1{2^{n+1}}=h,$ $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac 1{2^{n+1}}\cot \frac x{2^{n+1}}=\lim_{h\to0}\cos hx\cdot\lim_{h\to0}\frac{hx}{\sin hx}\cdot \frac1x=\frac1x$$

Comment: Hmm... is my answer right? 

And I am more interested in a source for this question than alternative methods. 

I surely appreciate your effort though. Thank you :)

Comment: @Isomorphism, yes our answers concur

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer too :)

Have you seen this question before?

Comment: @Isomorphism, just re-discovered Ex 2 in Page:414 of http://archive.org/details/planetrigonomet00lonegoog . There are many such before/after this

Answer (score 2):

The identity
$$
\cot(x)+\frac12\tan(x/2)=\frac12\cot(x/2)
$$
sort of leads you to the solution. Iterating gives your sum.

Comment: I didn't know this one.

Comment: @SohamChowdhury: the proof is given in lab's answer, but I reformat it here:
$$
\begin{align}
\cot(x)-\tan(x)
&=\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}-\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}\\
&=2\frac{\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x)}{2\sin(x)\cos(x)}\\
&=2\frac{\cos(2x)}{\sin(2x)}\\
&=2\cot(2x)
\end{align}
$$
the rest is repackaging to make it more obvious how to get the recursion.